# fmt:parseDate - a parse index locale can not be established

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Does anyone know the root cause of this error?  I am feeding known good data to the fmt:parseDate tag (its db driven data controlled by us), and yet this error randomly pops up.  I can't seem to find a way to replicate what causes this exception.

Comment: Lovely, a heisenbug. Assuming you see it again, would you post the stacktrace, if there is one, or what else the system's giving you?

Comment: Is it because the default [Locale](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) is not setup?

Comment: As I understand it, at start-up time, the default locale is automatically set by the Java runtime to match the host's current locale and if this is not possible, the en_US locale is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How open is the website - the Locale comes from the user preferences in some cases Accept--Language header - perhaps the user is sending a bad value, maybe its from a Chrome browser :) .  Here is a similar [example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-taglibs-user/200410.mbox/%3C200410141245.55548.f.tordini@kataweb.it%3E)